# Why declaring variable like that $var="";

Tags: php

Let me post the code in question:

```
session_start(); // some text 
$Var = "";
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    // some conditions
    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $var = some links or text here ;
}
else
{
    $var = link or text here;
}
```

Question is that: Why is `$var="";` declared first, then further down it is used in an `if` condition. I want to understand its logic and why can I write like that.

```
$var=header("Location: link.php");
```

Comment: In PHP you don't need to declare variables before you need to put their values into.

Comment: It's usually used when you want to concatenate strings.

Comment: If you are using Linux $var and $Var are not the same thing.. keep the lowercase or uppercase on your variable names.

Comment: `header()` returns `void`, so storing it's return value is completely pointless.

Comment: @demonofnight That's true for windows too.

Comment: @demonofnight: I believe it's PHP's language designer, so, it's must be true in anywhere where php run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although PHP doesn't require you to "declare" a variable before you use it in the way that some languages do, it can be useful to express your intent when writing the code. It's possible to use a variable before you ever assign to it (it's value will be taken to be `null`), but IDEs and code checkers, as well as PHP itself, will flag this as a warning, because you might have mistakenly typed the wrong variable name.

Assigning an empty value to a variable at the beginning of a section of code also prevents values "leaking" if the code gets rearranged, for instance if a loop is added. You might start with this:

```
if ( some_check($something) )
{
     $var = 'something';
}
echo $var;
```

But expand it to this later:

```
foreach ( $some_array as $some_item )
{
    if ( some_check($some_item) )
    {
         $var = 'something';
    }
    echo $var;
}
```

The subtle bug here is that once `$var` becomes `'something'` the first time, it never gets "cleared" on subsequent runs round the loop. "Initialising" the variable to an empty string makes it explicit when it "begins and ends" in a sense.

So you might instead start with this:

```
$var = '';
if ( some_check($something) )
{
     $var = 'something';
}
echo $var;
```

...which then naturally becomes this:

```
foreach ( $some_array as $some_item )
{
    $var = '';
    if ( some_check($some_item) )
    {
         $var = 'something';
    }
    echo $var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We often need to declare a variable outside the condition scope, in order we can use that variable again after the condition scope.
For instance, when counting inside a loop, and after the loop is done, we want to display the count variable.

Concerning `$var=header("Location: link.php");`, `header` function returns void, thus it's useless to use a var to store it result, but for other non-void function it's pretty handy sometimes.

Comment: That's not really true in PHP, because there is no such thing as "declaring" a variable. It can be important to *initialize* a variable at the right time, but it is not strictly a question of scope.